# How to filter model object array list with another String arrays

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to filter model object array list with another String array list

My model object is

```
class City {
    String id;
    String cat_id;
    String city_id;
    String title_en;
}
```

I have list of city objects `List<City> events;`

I want to filter `events` with another string arrays

```
List<String> city_ids = {2,12,24,25};
List<String> cat_ids = {301,386,303,346};
```

I only want `City` objects that have `city_id` and `cat_id` in these `String` arrays. How can i filter the Array List with these String Lists.

This is my version. How can i improve this

```
List<City> filtered_events = new ArrayList<>();
    if (filtered_categories.size() > 0) {
            for (String c : filtered_categories) {

                for (City city: events) {
                    if (c.equalsIgnoreCase(city.getCat_id())) {
                        filtered_events.add(city);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (filtered_cities.size() > 0) {
            for (String c : filtered_cities) {

                for (City city: events) {
                    if (c.equalsIgnoreCase(city.getCity_id())) {
                        filtered_events.add(city);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. One approach with java streams:

```
List<City> filteredCities = events.stream()
    .filter(c -> city_ids.contains(c.city_id) && cat_ids.contains(c.cat_id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()):
```